# Set default timezone in Databricks to ESTA

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-databricks

I'm running code in Databricks but somehow unixtimestamp values are not different. On debugging I get to know, because databricks is configured with UTC timezone.
Please advise how can I change default timezone to EST in Databricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in the `cluster -> configuration -> Advanced Option -> spark`, set the spark parameter:

```
spark.sql.session.timeZone Asia/Hongkong
```

It will impact any sql statement time zone.

If you want to set the time zone for all data nodes, you need to add an initial script and set the unix time zone. so that some thing like the python `datetime.dateime.now()`, would be the set timezone.

Comment: Thanks I worked. Can you specify sample command which I can use to set default timezone in each node to EST.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set time zone while defining spark session :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession as PySparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf


TIMEZONE = 'AFRICA/CAT'

class SparkSession:

    def __init__(self, config=[]):
        config.append(tuple(('spark.sql.session.timeZone',TIMEZONE)))
        self.conf = SparkConf().setAll(config)
        self.spark = (PySparkSession.builder
                      .config(conf=self.conf)
                      .enableHiveSupport()
                      .getOrCreate())
```